# Where should I post such a question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, books

I have a question and I'm not sure where I ought to ask it.

> Should we read previous revisions or editions of the same book before we start reading the newest edition?
>
> For an example:
>
> I want to read [WPF Unleashed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328917) by Adam Nathan it was published back in 2006, and now there is a newer version in Jun 2010: [WPF Unleashed 4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672331195) covering .NET Framework 4.
>
> Is it better way to go edition by edition to know how technology is evolving, or just go by the newest edition and assume that previous versions may no more be relevant as newer will cover everything.

**N.B.** I am afraid that this question may be out context of a Q&A site, but nobody other than fellow programmers can answer this question. (Of course a librarian or book-seller cannot answer it). Please suggest me in which Stack Exchange site I should post it.

Comment: As it is not suited to a Q&A site it is not suited to any of the Stackexchange sites. Why post a question you already know is off topic? Just buy the latest one and read that.

Comment: @vascogotlost: Yes I do understand, but then whom to ask. Should I write e-mails to each and every authors of book and ask them to suggest..definitely not !

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh, I see the ` Or please suggest me in which StackOverflow forum should I post it.`. Just that the main body of the question was asking us the question itself. Actually I'll edit it.

Comment: Your problem seems to be your expectation that Stack Exchange is meant to provide a place to ask such a question in the first place.

Comment: Ask yourself...

Comment: Regarding the close-votes: Technically this question is *allowed* here, as it is a question for specifying the scope of the site. It's better if a user comes here and asks then to throw random questions at random sites.

Comment: @Kobobby I think many of the close votes probably came from the original post before it was [revised](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/130160/revisions). My flag and down vote certainly did.

Comment: +5 to all the people who provided their valuable inputs for improving the question, rather than just feeling happy for downvote. Discussion for improvement is better than a downvote.

Comment: Nah, this question is worthy of a commentless downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that question suits any existing Stack Exchange site, as it doesn't require a specific expertise to be answered.

The "not constructive" closing reason, which would probably apply to such question, has the following description:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or **specific expertise**; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

The answer would be "read the latest edition/revision available." There isn't any reason to read the previous edition, if you just want to have updated information about a topic.

Comment: If you _had_ to fit it into a site, it's prog.SE. But I agree that it would probably be off topic there as well. Note that `it doesn't require a specific expertise to be answered.` isn't a valid no-site-exists excuse, IMO. UX.SE and MSO don't require specific expertise.

Comment: I am not saying that as "no site exists" excuse. I am referring to the expertise of who answers, not who asks, and the "not constructive" closing reason.

Comment: Aah, I see :) +1